# LWC form is submitted to server even required field have error

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

html file

```
<template>
        <lightning-input 
                    label="First Name" 
                    name="FirstName" 
                    onchange={handleChange} 
                    required
                    class="slds-var-p-around_x-small"
                    value={leadRecord.FirstName}>
        </lightning-input>
        <lightning-input 
                    label="Last Name"  
                    name="LastName"
                    required
                    onchange={handleChange} 
                    class="slds-var-p-around_x-small"
                    value={leadRecord.LastName}>
        </lightning-input>
        <lightning-input 
                    label="Phone" 
                    name="Phone" 
                    type="tel"
                    maxlength="10"
                    onchange={handleChange} 
                    class="slds-var-p-around_x-small"
                    value={leadRecord.Phone}>
        </lightning-input>
  <lightning-button
                label="Create Lead"
                variant="brand"
                **disabled={validateInputs}**
                onclick={createLead}>
            </lightning-button>
</template>
```

Js file

```
@track disableBtn = true;

  handleChange(event) {
            this.leadRecord[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    }


---------- NOT working 
get validateInputs(){
        
        if(this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(element => {
         if(!element.checkValidity()) {
              element.reportValidity();
              this.disableBtn = false;
          }
      }))
  
       return this.disableBtn;
     }


---------- NOT WORKING
fields={};
fields = this.leadRecord;
var objRecordInput = {'apiName' : 'Lead', fields};

createLead() {

        createRecord(objRecordInput)
        .then(response => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: "Success",
                    message: " Lead created successfully! " + response.id,
                    variant: "success"
                })
            );
        }).catch(error => {
        alert('Error: ' +JSON.stringify(error));
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: "Error creating record",
                    message: error,
                    variant: "error"
                })
            );
        
        }).finally(() => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I want to disable the submit button until all required fields are filled with a value. form is submitted even if required fields are not filled. I have 10required fields. I tried multiple ways like to use count in handle change but if we skip to fill the field, count wont work. Any inputs please? I have seen may people asked this question in different ways, but those solutions seems not working for me.

****update****
[image]

[image]

After refresh is it showing all required fields in red and enables submit(create Lead).
Immediate response is appreciated

Comment: @sfdcfox please have look

Comment: There is a typo: you wrote `element.requried` instead of `element.required`. By the way, you should paste the whole JS file or at least every part used in the template, like `disableBtn` and where is referenced `validateInputs`

Comment: @RubenDg I have updated the code. I tried multiple things I have missed some things to paste

Comment: @RubenDG I dont see the difference, But I have changed the code with below suggestion. Could you have fresh look

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the below code-:

```
 get validateInputs(){

   const allValid = [
        ...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input'),
    ].reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
        inputCmp.reportValidity();
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
    }, true);
    return allValid }
```

Comment: You didn't scope `allValid` to `this` in the logic part of this method. The code is also poorly linted.

Comment: @prajjwal-agrawal it is not working please find the update in the post

Comment: I have updated the code. You can try this out.

Comment: @prajjwalagrawal I have tired. initially loading all required fields are red. can we do private chat?

Answer (score 0):

Using a getter probably isn't ideal, because getters only execute during a life cycle event (i.e. a property is updated on the controller).

Instead, you can just add this to the input handler:

```
disableBtn = true;
handleChange(event) {
    this.leadRecord[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.disableBtn = ![
    ...this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input")
    ].every((input) => input.checkValidity());
}
```

Then, disable the button with the flag:

```
<lightning-button
    label="Create Lead"
    variant="brand"
    disabled={disableBtn}
    onclick={createLead}>
</lightning-button>
```

Do not call `reportValidity()` until you're ready to show the validations on the screen.

Comment: @sfdxfox right after loading, required fields are not red, but it is not enabling the button

Comment: @sfdxfox What I am trying to achieve is  required fields are not filled but submit button is submitting the record.

Comment: @Mentee then, you don't want validation until they hit Submit? If that's the case, don't disable the button, just use the standard check and report design.

Comment: i did that try it is not working, I thought disabling the button till 'all the required fields are filled and then enabling it would be best' but it is not working